# Without using conjunctions in conditions of selection operators

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Let's say there is a table call ITEM and it contains 3 attributes(name, id, price):

```
name      id      price

Apple     1       3
Orange    1       3
Banana    2       4
Cherry    3       5
Mango     1       3
```

How should I write a query to use a constants selection operator to select those item that have same prices and same ids ? The first thing come into my mind is use a rename operator to rename id to id', and price to price', then union it with the ITEM table,  but since I need to select 2 tuples (price=price' & id=id') from the table, how can I select them without using the conjunctions operator in relational algebra ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure but for me, it would be something like this in relational calculus:

[image]

and then in SQL:

```
SELECT name FROM ITEM i WHERE
    EXISTS ITEM u
        AND u.name != i.name
        AND u.price=i.price
        AND u.id = i.id
```

But still, I think your assumption is right, you can still do it by renaming. I do believe it is a bit longer than what I did above.